# Google chrome's tabbing behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a simple web form which is having four input text fields.

Assume I have currently focused on 2nd text field and now I'm moving out from it and clicking on an empty area of the window (so now the focus will not be there).

If I press the tab key now, then apparently it should move to the 3rd text field. This happens in firefox, IE and even in Chrome 27 when I checked. But **in Chrome 33 and latest Chrome versions** focus goes to 1st text field**.

Is this the default behavior of Chrome latest versions? Are there any possibilities to avoid this and get the same behavior of IE and firefox for tabbing feature?

**Note:** *You can test this scenario using gmail's login page form.*

Comment: Do you have a reference which says that your desired behaviour is the *correct* behaviour? (standards wise)

Comment: are they in correct order in HTML source?

Comment: @David-SkyMesh: I don't have any reference says that behavior is correct but that is the behavior which I need.